# Angular2 Data binding between Components

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template

I started developing an Angular2 App recently based on the MEAN stack and I ran into some problems with data binding. I looked at the documentation and every question on here, but I can't find my mistake. I hope someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

One of my components is called by

```
<app-canvas-block-card [block]=block [canvas]=canvas></app-canvas-block-card>
```

Both properties are accepted in the CanvasBlockCardComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ICanvasBlock } from '../../../../interfaces/canvas-block.interface';
import { ICanvas } from '../../../../interfaces/canvas.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas-block-card',
  templateUrl: './canvas-block-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas-block-card.component.scss']
})
export class CanvasBlockCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() canvas: ICanvas;
  @Input() block: ICanvasBlock;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.dir(this.canvas);
    console.dir(this.block);
  }

}
```

But when I try to bind them to the next component in the template of CanvasBlockCardComponent by using

```
<a [routerLink]="['/canvas', canvas._id, block._id]" [block]="block" [canvas]="canvas"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

I get errors thrown:

```
Can't bind to 'block' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
Can't bind to 'canvas' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
```

The component (CanvasDetailComponent) called by the link looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ICanvas } from '../../../../interfaces/canvas.interface';
import { ICanvasBlock } from '../../../../interfaces/canvas-block.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas-detail',
  templateUrl: './canvas-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./canvas-detail.component.scss']
})
export class CanvasDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() canvas: ICanvas;
  @Input() block: ICanvasBlock;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused the way you are trying to bind data. Per your code above, you are trying to bind the data to an "a" element, which is not an Angular component of your, that's why you get those errors which are self explanatory tho.

What you are probably, by my guesses, looking for is:

```
<canvas-detail-component [block]="block" [canvas]="canvas"></canvas-detail-component>
```

And then, within that component, you'll have an html to render, there is where you will have your code:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/canvas', canvas._id, block._id]">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</a>
```

Hope it helps